# Difference between user complete and omni complete in vim

Tags: vim, plugins, vimrc

I'm using [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) in Vim 7.3. When entering some code I'd expect it to suggest completions based on the class of the variable:

```
$db = new MembersDatabase();
$db-> /* Sugest addMember, printMembers, __construct */
```

Instead vim just outputs

```
-- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found
```

However if I hit `<C-x><C-o>` omni completion pops up and shows me what I expect.

Isn't [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) supposed to be smarter than that? Can I just disable user complete since (in this instance) omni obviously is what I want.

Additional question, on some screenshots for [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) they show method signatures when suggesting completions, how do I enable those?

[Link to my vim config](https://bitbucket.org/MindTwister/vimconfig) [Pastibin of .vimrc](http://pastebin.com/m7TxLfqv)

Answer (score 1):

```
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.php = '[^. \t]->\h\w*\|\h\w*::'
```

is supposed to kick the plugin into omnicompletion mode after a `->` or a `::`. You should post an issue on GitHub.

Also I don't see method signatures in any of those screenshots but the PHP omnicompletion script already does that in small preview window.